# How to set cell size for vector to raster conversion in QGIS GRASS plugin?

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, vector

I'm converting a vector (loaded in GRASS plugin in QGIS (1.7.0.-wroclaw) and would like to convert this to a raster with a defined cell size. At the same time I need a value from the attribute tabel to be used as raster value.

This tool: v.to.rast.attr

looks promising. however, I cannot define the output cell size, or a snap raster. In ArcGIS (esri) this is quite easy. Is there a way to do the same in QGIS?

Answer (score 3):

In GRASS you define the raster cell size for each raster operation by setting the REGION parameters. In QGIS you find the proper button in the GRASS toolbar.

Comment: > > > In GRASS you define the raster cell size for each raster operation by
> setting the REGION parameters. In QGIS you find the proper button in
> the GRASS toolbar. Where Grass toolbar? could u explain more ?

Comment: Have a look to the QGIS user manual, there is an entire chapter about the QGIS/GRASS integration and it describes very well all the meaning of the buttons in the GRASS toolbar.

Comment: there's nothing like a good ol' RTFM answer...

Answer (score 3):

Once the mapset is enabled, go to

Plugins - GRASS - Edit Current GRASS region

Change the cell size under 'Resolution'