# Running nvis tool in QGIS GRASS

Tags: qgis, dem, contour, nviz

I am trying to follow this workflow: [[Generating DEM from contour Shapefile using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60228/how-to-generate-a-dem-from-a-countour-shapefile)] and it's running fine, and when I hit view output or view results I end up with a flat raster with shading associated with the heights of my contours on screen.

However, I want to see the 3D terrain with hillshading etc, and potentially export a 3d mesh, and from research, think that the nvis module in GRASS can do this for me, but when I try to run this I get the error "module nvis not found", and QGIS crashes and dies.

When I go to Manage and Install Plugins, Grass is there, and it has let me perform all the other modules I've needed.

What do I do with this?

Link to sample data here (.shp+.gml): https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mwxlr3ij78d8gkr/lKwgu3Pafu

Answer (score 6):

You have two solutions:

#### 1) from the GRASS plugin: you are working in GRASS GIS, not in QGIS, so you need to know GRASS GIS

- you need to first open a LOCATION/MAPSET of GRASS (from the plugin) or create a new LOCATION/MAPSET

[image]

- you will then have access to the GRASS Tools

[image]

to:

- import the shapefile in the MAPSET (v.in.ogr.qgis)
- transform the shapefile in a raster if you want to use the r. modules ([v.to.rast](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.to.rast.html))
- fix the GRASS region ([g.region](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/g.region.html))
- use [r.contour](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.contour.html), [r.surf.idw](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.surf.idw.html), [r.surf.idw2](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.surf.idw2.html) or [v.surf.rst](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.surf.rst.html) to generate the DEM
- use [nviz](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/nviz.html) to visualise the DEM, change the color, drape a raster layer or add another DEM and/or vector files.

[image] [image]

#### 2) from  GRASS in the Processing Toolbox:

- you are working in QGIS. In fact, the use of GRASS GIS is transparent, no need to open GRASS GIS, import the shapefile in a LOCATION/MAPSET or fixing a region, everything is done automatically by Processing.

[image]

#### 3) What is the difference ?

The Processing version is more limited, you may only view the DEM, with no possibility to drape a raster, add another DEM or vector layers