# Error 5 Pixel type must be FLOAT32

Tags: qgis, dem

I am trying to create a DEM from topographic contours vector. I have already sucessfully created a raster using the interpolation plugin. Firstly, I don't know why or how to ccontrol the output settings when creating a raster so that it can be  FLOAT32 compliant. Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Where did you get that error?

Comment: When I try to create a DEM in QGIS 2.4.

Comment: You might be better served by following the advice in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60228/how-to-generate-a-dem-from-a-contour-shapefile?rq=1

Comment: So I think I resolved the issue by using a different DEM raster (of the same zone). I think there might have been an issue with the source contours (either having topographic errors or not having the correct layer characteristics). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the datatype from integer to float with gdal_translate:

```
gdal_translate -ot Float32 src_dataset dst_dataset
```

You can do that in QGIS with Raster -> Conversion -> Translate, using the command line box