# Creating DEM Contour files from shapefile line data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, vector, profile

There are many question occurring on this forum regarding this issue, however the issue I am facing has not been answered in [Generating DEM from contour Shapefile using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60228/generating-dem-from-contour-shapefile-using-qgis), which is that I have contour `line data.` Not `point data.`

Following the steps in [Generating DEM from contour Shapefile using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60228/generating-dem-from-contour-shapefile-using-qgis). I have used `SAGA Tool` in the `Processing Toolbox`. Selected the `Triangulation Tool` from the `Raster Creation Tools`.

At this point It asks for the 'points' required for rasterising. But I want to input 'line data' does anyone know how to do this?

below shows the 'line data expressed in QGIS'
[image]

the purpose behind this is due to the fact I need to create a 'height profile' using the `Profile tool` to create a cross section area from contours as seen in the example below.

[image]

I am using QGIS V 3.4

Comment: You can convert the contour lines into points with a tool like `points along geometry` or `extract vertices`

Comment: Thankyou @CSK, I also found out another way which I will put below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question and looked everywhere! **Finally a solution** - you need to use "TIN interpolation". This video explains it perfectly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PhJ77uHlTJA

It demonstrates other processes as well but the main thing is they used contour line data and created a DEM. Really good explanation as well.

Key tools used:

- TIN interpolation (Processing Toolbox)
- Slope (you can skip this one) (Processing Toolbox)
- Hillshade (Raster tab)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the

> MMQGIS plugin

Once added it will show up in the tool bar at the top of the screen. Select/highland the 'line.data' layer you want to convert to 'points.data'. click on `MMQGIS` and a drop down will appear. Then click on `Modify` and then `Convert Geometry Type`

Then a box appears as seen below -->

[image]

Change the 'New Geometry Type' to nodes from default 'line centers' and save the output file. Once ready click apply and this will change line data to point data